# NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 131: laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

For some reason I'm getting this error

> NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 131: No query results for model [App\Modules\Menus\Models\Menu].

I shouldn't be getting this error since I'm not referencing the menu model at all in my dashboard function.

I've done `route:clear` and `route:cache` without any success.

Here is my CustomersController

```
namespace App\Modules\Customers\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Modules\Menus\Models\Menu;
use App\Modules\Customers\Models\Customer;
use DB;
use Validator;
Use Mail;
use Auth;

class CustomersController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if(auth('customer_admin')->attempt(array('email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password'))))
        {
            if(auth()->guard('customer_admin')->user()->is_activated == '0')
            {
                $this->logout();
                return back()->with('error', 'Please activate your account.');
            }

            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }else{
            return back()->with('error', 'Your email/password combination is wrong.');
        }
    }

    public function dashboard()
    {
        echo "dashboard";
    }
}
```

My web.php routes

```
Route::get('/signup', [
    'uses' => 'CustomersController@signup',
    'as' => 'customer.signup'
]);

Route::post('/signup', [
    'uses' => 'CustomersController@postSignup',
    'as' => 'post.signup'
]);

Route::get('customer/activation/{token}', [
    'uses' => 'CustomersController@customerActivation',
    'as' => 'activation',
]);

Route::post('/login', [
    'uses' => 'CustomersController@login',
    'as' => 'login'
]);


// CUSTOMER LOGIN
Route::get('/dashboard', [
    'uses' => 'CustomersController@dashboard',
    'as' => 'dashboard'
]);

Route::get('/logout', [
    'uses' => 'CustomersController@logout',
    'as' => 'logout'
]);
```

The full stack trace

```
in Handler.php line 131
at Handler->prepareException(object(ModelNotFoundException)) in Handler.php 
line 109
at Handler->render(object(Request), object(ModelNotFoundException)) in 
Handler.php line 47
at Handler->render(object(Request), object(ModelNotFoundException)) in 
Pipeline.php line 82
at Pipeline->handleException(object(Request), 
object(ModelNotFoundException)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php 
line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php 
line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php 
line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 561
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php 
line 520
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54

1/2 ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 395: No query results for 
model [App\Modules\Menus\Models\Menu].

in Builder.php line 395
at Builder->firstOrFail() in OpenController.php line 52
at OpenController->content('dashboard')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(OpenController), 'content'), array('id' 
=> 'dashboard')) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('content', array('id' => 'dashboard')) in 
ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(OpenController), 
'content') in Route.php line 204
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 160
at Route->run() in Router.php line 559
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php 
line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php 
line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php 
line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 561
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php 
line 520
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in 
CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in 
Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php 
line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace.

Comment: @PankitGami - I've added the stack trace to my question

Comment: Do you have any `OpenController.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

I see:

```
Route::post('/login', [
    'uses' => 'CustomersController@login',
    'as' => 'login'
]);
```

How about the respective:

```
Route::get('/login', [
    'uses' => 'CustomersController@loginPage',
    'as' => 'page.login'
]);
```

You could also redirect the user to login route when they hit dashboard route.

```
public function dashboard()
{
    return redirect("login"); //redirect to login page
}
```

As an aside, re-arrange your use statements to:

```
use DB;
Use Mail;
use Auth;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Modules\Menus\Models\Menu;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Modules\Customers\Models\Customer;
```

This has nothing to do with the error you are having, its just a good practice. My answer to your question is in your routes file like shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using `Laravel 5.2` given the routes file named `web.php`

Your routes are loaded into [`RouteServiceProvider`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.2/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php) and it assumes all the controllers are located under namespace `App\Http\Controllers`

I've noticed that your controller is under `App\Modules\Customers\Http\Controllers` namespace.

So the correct way to define routes for it is specifying the complete namespace to it. See the example:

```
<?php

Route::get('/signup', [
    'uses' => '\App\Modules\Customers\Http\Controllers\CustomersController@signup',
    'as' => 'customer.signup'
]);
```

Another (and better) way is to define a dedicated `RouteServiceProvider` for each "module" of your application. Check your default provider under `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file to know how it works.